# I can't locate my host directory, which I attached to Docker

Tags: database, unix, docker, arangodb

I have a slight problem, I've been trying to get some persistent data with ArangoDB and Docker. I passed the argument to Docker which attaches the hosts directory to a path within Docker. It's all fine to this point, but I'm stuck in an enigma where the hell this directory is.

1) This is a sample command which resembles mine:

```
docker run -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD='mypass' -p 80:8529 -d -v myhostfolder:/var/lib/arangodb3 arangodb
```

So, the problem is i can't find **myhostfolder** anywhere on my host machine which runs docker. The data within it is persistent and I can access it, but only through the docker container. I think that the data is somewhere on my host machine, I've been trying to pass a couple of these "relative" folders and they all keep persistent data so I doubt that the data is in the actual docker container.

2) If I do something like this (providing an absolute path)

```
docker run -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD='mypass' -p 80:8529 -d -v /home/myhostfolder:/var/lib/arangodb3 arangodb
```

then I have no issues with locating the **/home/myhostfolder**.

So my question is, where on my **OS X 10.12** is the **myhost** folder from example 1)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you do this aren't you mounting a host dir into the container? I'm not certain of the behavior here when the dir doesn't exist but I doubt it will create the dir on the host. Seen [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)? There's additional notes on specific OS usage as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host-dir can either be an absolute path or a name value. If you supply an absolute path for the host-dir, Docker bind-mounts to the path you specify. If you supply a name, Docker creates a named volume by that name.
Refer https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume.

In your case, as ***`myhostfolder`*** is a name, docker creates a named volume. Execute the below command which lists the volumes. A volume with name `myhostfolder` will be shown.

```
docker volume ls
```